# What is the meaning of "Vrepit Sa"?

Tags: dialogue, lion-force-voltron, voltron

In [*Netflix Voltron*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5580664/) all Galras say the word "Vrepit Sa", Does this word have a meaning or Is it simply a army salute?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

This [site](http://aminoapps.com/page/voltron-legendary-defenders/266382/vrepit-sa-theories) may come across as a bit rude but here is a meaning (a possible meaning):

> Vrepit Sa Theories???
>
> What do you all think "Vrepit Sa" means? AKA The thing all Galras say. Is it simply a military salute with the same meaning as a hand salute on earth? Or does it actually translate to something? I read on an old tumblr post that in Slovak, "Vrepit Sa" is a phrase that translates to "to stick" or "to thrust", and the theory was that Vrepit Sa meant something similar to "Onward!" Since that's KIND OF similar to "to stick or to thrust". What do YOU think Vrepit Sa means?

Answer (score 3):

In season 6 episode 1 it is defined as meaning "Killing Thrust"

Answer (score 0):

I believe there's an episode where it's literally translated: "victory or death" after some story about the origin of the species.

Comment: This would be a better answer if you could narrow down which episode a little.